# How can I share the internet connection on my Mac

Tags: macos, internet, desktop-computer

I have an iPad 3G and I'm using Game Center to compare my scores against other players.

Right now, i don't have internet on my iPad, but do have it on my desktop computer.

Is there a way to utilize it, to sync my scores in Game Center ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up an [ad-hoc wireless network with internet connection sharing](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx).

[image: Courtesy Microsoft]

Comment: How to do it on a Mac ? I've enabled AirPort and "Internet Sharing", but iPad does't sees it ...

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-wireless-ad-hoc-network-between-macs.html

Comment: Thanks. I've figured it out.
I need to setup "Shared Ethernet connection" For that devices, that are using "Air Port"